# Fixed-Point vs Floating-Point and Performance

Tags: ios, audio, floating-point, signal-processing, fixed-point

I have an iOS audio app that is using floating point to do it's processing right now. On the newer iOS devices it works flawlessly. However, on older devices it stalls/can't process it (no sound will come out).

Should I convert my algorithms to use a fixed-point system to work around this to improve the performance. Or should I just improve the algorithms I'm using to process them (as far as I know some of the algorithms I am using are mostly optimized). Is it worth trying to do fixed-point work in iOS?

Thanks!

### EDIT

I'm starting to think that it's a processor speed issue and now I'm thinking I have to just optimize/improve my algorithms. Should I be going with this approach?

Comment: The question as-is seems too broad. What audio processing are you doing specifically? How did you determine that the app is inoperable on older devices due to floating-point performance as opposed to some other reason? Are you using the fastest available floating-point emulation?

Comment: @njuffa I'm synthesizing waveforms, doing digital audio effects, etc. And when I try to synthesize the audio it works when I synthesize one waveform. However, when I try to synthesize 2 or 3 or 4 waveforms it stops playing back. You don't hear anything at all. More like a small blip when it cuts out which I'm assuming is just an abrupt interruption to the stream of audio

Answer (score 1):

On any iOS device that supports iOS 9, using short floats for DSP computation (multiply-accumulates) for most DSP algorithms is as fast or faster than using 32-bit scaled integers.  The NEON vector unit can dispatch 4 per cycle if you can keep the pipeline fed.

Comment: Thanks man! That's useful to know. However, I think it has to do with processor speed of older devices.... I'm checking out the memory when running it and when I start synthesizing two waveforms (along with everything else) it shoots up from 20% to 90%! That's fooking crazy. I need to definitely rethink how I'm doing my signal processing algorithms over again.

Comment: A single CPU core on an iPhone 6s is on the order of 5 times faster than an old iPhone 4s at generic FP math thruput.